# Print PDF on EPSON TM U950/Thermal printer

Tags: html, pdf, fonts, thermal-printer, epson

Our Struts 2 web app generates a PDF of a receipt, which has to be printed on EPSON TM U950 thermal printer. Those printers uses their raster font or cpi font. When i print the PDF, the text is a litle bit unreadable, it doesn't print it very well. We don't have a chance to develop a desktop app or something like that to print it, we just can use the printer dialog in PDF reader, in this case Adobe Acrobat.

Is there a way to use the same font of TM U950 printer or a similar font generated in the PDF which shows well on the print? For example, a font file and included in the html page using CSS features or something like that?

Comment: This question is unanswerable as we don't have access to your printer.  Seems more like a hardware question also.

Comment: What do you mean? The printer model is an EPSON TM U950.

Comment: @OscarCalderon that information is unlikely to be useful to anyone. Does the text look fine when you open the PDF in Acrobat or even Firefox? Then this is a hardware problem and you should probably contact Epson first, as part of the ["you need to do your own research first, before asking on Stackoverflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) policy. Does it also render poorly? Then you probably want a different font that both looks good, and is PostScript compatible with the Epson (so probably a professional .otf). Which ones have you tried?

Comment: Well, i think that's no hardware problem because i experienced the same with other EPSON TM U950 printers. About the font, i'm looking for PostScript fonts but i only found A11 TrueType font. Do you know where i can find those fonts? Regards.